# Load image from url

Tags: java, android

I want to load image from url and I am using this code:

```
URL url = new URL(myurl);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

I am running the app in a device with android 2.3 and works fine but in other device with android 4.4 app crashes and close.

Somebody knows why? is there other code compatible?

Thanks

Here is my log cat:

```
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878): Process: com.my.feed, PID: 3878
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:179)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at com.my.feed.LazyAdapterComentarios.getView(LazyAdapterComentarios.java:85)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:453)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2552)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1915)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1109)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1291)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5603)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
12-26 15:17:01.993: E/AndroidRuntime(3878):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer
```

The line who crash is:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
```

Comment: can you please provide the logcat with the error when the app crashes?

Comment: I have updated my question with the log cat

Comment: Your code to download the image is perfect. Just put your code inside a background thread. You can use an `AsyncTask` too.

Answer (score 2):

> Somebody knows why?

You should, by [examining LogCat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this) and looking at the Java stack trace associated with your crash.

In this case, I expect that you will find that you are getting [a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception).

> is there other code compatible?

There are [many](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/46), [many](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fkoush%2Fion&ei=EFydVN3mFIalNoCXgOAI&usg=AFQjCNGiONso8psVfvce97KlxYN7ZDVjrg&bvm=bv.82001339,d.eXY) libraries for loading images off of a network asynchronously and using them to populate an `ImageView`. Personally, I lean towards [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

Comment: You can try with 'Universal Image Loader' which is easier to use.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my question with the log cat

Answer (score 0):

```
private void callWeb(URL myurl) {
    HttpGet httpRequest = null;
    httpRequest = new HttpGet(myurl.toURI());

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpRequest);

    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    if (entity != null) {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = entity.getContent();
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            // options.inSampleSize = 2;
            final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream,
                    null, options);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }
            entity.consumeContent();
        }
    }
}
```

Check if helps?